# How to determine the last nonzero decimal digit in a float?

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

I am writing a float printing and formatting library and want to avoid printing trailing zero digits.

For this I would like to accurately determine the last nonzero digit within the first N decimal places after the decimal point. I wonder whether there is a particular efficient way to do this.

Comment: I don't have a proof, but my intuition is that you just have to work out the first `N` decimal places and then check for zeroes. The reason behind my guess is that if you're printing (say) `1.00049` to 3 decimal places, then to know that there any trailing zeros you must establish that the 4th place is not `5`. I don't think there's any great shortcut to tell you that without telling you the preceding digits. I'm sure there are plenty of little shortcuts toward working out all 4 places efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (non-trivial) problem has been fully solved. The idea is to print exactly enough digits so that if you converted the printed digits back to a floating-point number, you would get exactly the number you started with.

The relevant paper is "Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately", by Robert Burger and R. Kent Dybvig. You can download it [here](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.52.2247).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert the float to a string and then trim the trailing zeros.

I don't think this is very efficient, but i feel there is probably no simplier algorithm

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout.precision(n);
```

//where n is the digits you want to display after the decimal.
  If there is a zero present before the precision limit but after decimal,
  it will be avoided automatically.

```
eg. std::cout.precision(5);
```

then my conidition is evaluated to be 5.55000
only 5.55 will be printed

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to put all digits in a `char[N]` and check the last digit before printing. But I bet you have thought about that yourself.

The only other solution I can think of, is that the decimal part of `2^(-n)` has `n` non-zero digits.

So if the last non-zero in the binary representation is `2^(-n)`, there will be exactly `n` non-zero digits in the decimal expansion. Therefor looking at the *binary* representation will tell you something about the *decimal* representation.

However, this is only a partial solution, as rounding could introduce additional trailing zeros.